# How to check the permissions to navigate the page in tree view child node using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, treeview

i am using one **tree view** control in asp.net, in this tree view i can give the navigation urls in child nodes , `my problem is user click the child nodes first check the user login (or) not if the user was logged, open the navigation page other wise open the login page` please give me suggestion about that if u have any idea in that topic please..

i click the child node which event fired where i can write the code pls give me example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

If you have master page , than check for any session vriable like this

```
if( session["userid"]==null )//this mean that user logged out or session is expire
{
 // go to login page
}
```

here is good example : [Redirect to Login page on session expiration (ASP.NET)](http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2007/09/05/115173.aspx)

**Old one**

Better way to do it not load those link in treeview control which are not beloging to given user....load those link in treeview which is beloging to given user role ...

so your databse query would be like

```
select pagelinks form the pages where userrole = @myrole
```

there is no sense in load links in tree view which are not beloging to given userrol its not good practice.. for end user this not good interface .. we caled this concept as **Authorization**

you can read and userstand about : [ASP.NET Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx) from this msdn link...

Comment: ... and also still check on the page itself. Make sure you don't get "security by obscurity".

Comment: i have no database my files are application only how to check the condition which event is fired when child node is clicked

Comment: @hmkmudiam  - you need to check Authtication and authorization on msdn this will help you to achieve your task...database is just example how you can achieve the things...

Comment: i click the child node which event fired where i can write the code pls give me example

Comment: sorry i think ur understanding is some worng way in the page load i can check the user login or not i can pass the session["username"] so noproblem that authentications

Comment: i have click the child node the session is empty open the login page other wise open the which page i allocated statically

Comment: @hmkmudiam  - check edited answer might hlpe you and also visit the link of the answer give you idea how to achieve it ...

Comment: ya that thing i can check it but that condition is checked in tree view child node clicked example http://www.expertlivetraining.com/Courses.aspx check this in courses click the child node that time only check the session empty or not

Comment: u can see testing -->automation child tab

Comment: hi now i have one another problem click the child node that time i attached the navigation url click on second time only display the file but i have first click attach the url and open it how to write the code to open the file

Answer (score 0):

Check the authentication every time when your site receive request. Redirect to login page for those  accessing page token required

Comment: my problem is not authentication click the child node that time check the session["id"] empty or not empty redirect to login page that code where i can write the treeview event

Comment: @hmkmudiam, sorry but not quite get you, but here maybe your answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodecheckchanged.aspx